# Is it correct to say that $\lim_{x \to \infty} \left( \frac{3x+2}{-3x+1}\right)^{2x} = e^2$?

Tags: calculus, limits

Is it correct to say that $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \left( \frac{3x+2}{-3x+1}\right)^{2x} = e^2$$

I am confused since Wolfram gives me the answer on the image below.

[image]

Comment: It is hard to define $u^v$ when $u$ is negative and $v$ is real. Is $x$ perhaps meant to be an integer limit? Wolfram is suggesting that the entire unit circle in the complex plane are limit points, not saying that the limit is $e^{2}$.

Comment: The limit $e^2$ is only correct when you restrict the values to $x$ being an integer - then $(1-3x)^{2x}=(3x-1)^{2x}$, and you have positive values. Not entirely sure what Wolfram is trying to say with its limit value. That said, it seems like WA is actually wrong, given its approximate formula for the terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like WA had a little problem. I have no idea what it means by $e^{2i0\text{ to }\pi}$, but even its own approximation of the terms as:

$$e^{2i\pi x + 2 +O(1/x)}$$

Would indicate the limit is points on the circle of radius $e^2$, rather than points of the circle of radius $1$, as its answer would seem to imply.

That said, as noted by myself and others, the limit is problematic if the limit is taken over $x$ real, as opposed to $x$ an integer. While it isn't formal, custom is for $\lim_{x\to\infty}$ to mean $x$ is allowed to take non-integer values, and we choose a variable like $m$ or $n$ if we want the limit to be interpreted as an integer limit. If $x$ is restricted to integers, then the limit is definitely $e^2$.

Wolfram alpha seems to assume that all limits are real limits.

Comment: thank you for the clear explanation.

Answer (score 1):

The problem from the fact that your limit is. $=e^{2xlog({{(3x+2)}\over{-3x+1}})}$. But $log({{(3x+2)}\over{-3x+1}}$ does not make sense as $x$ goes towards infinity since the limit of $(3x+2)/(-3x+1)$ is negative.